# Who are the AU chat room owners?

Tags: support, chat

I was just wondering (as I have not seen any body with a name like *this* in the AU chat room) who the room owners in the main [Ubuntu chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) were, so I thought I would ask a question about it here as this seemed to be the most relevant place to ask it. So who?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Going into the info page and the Access tab for the room will very quickly answer this.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room?tab=access)

Note that "Owner" doesn't mean "Founder", it just means people who administrate to a point.

Diamond mods have God rights in most all of the chat channels regardless.

[image]

Comment: I would have if I were not in doubt about what you really wanted to say :-)

Comment: @guntbert i think the rewording worked.  Considering yesterday I had 3 hours of sleep the night prior i was a little crazy to the point of "Not logically thinking all arguments through"